# Refactoring and solving for h ...

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I have the following formula:

$$
X = \frac{1}{\sin(h + 244/(165 + 47h^{1.1}))},
$$

I have attempted a few iterations, and I must be very rusty, but I was looking for a way to solve for $h$, such that $h= \cdots$ ?

Any pro-tips and pointers would be great ...

Comment: This  won't have a nice algebraic solution even after undoing the $\sin$ with $\arcsin$. You will need numerical methods.

Comment: You can untangle everything...kill the fraction, divide by $X$, take the arcsin, then kill the fraction again. But even after all of that, you'll need a numerical method like Newton's method anyway.